# How to toggle a class on the body with React onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a button that opens a div that looks like a modal.

On click of this button, I want to add a class on to the body, then on click of a close button, I want to remove this class.

How would you do this in React functional component with `useEffect` / `useState`?

Comment: Usually is not a good idea to directly manipulate the `DOM`. But you can use `getElementsByTagName` or similar to select the `body` and apply  `class` and `style` to it

Answer (score 1):

You could use `this.setState` like this in Components

```js
....
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState((state) => { 
    addClass: !state.addClass
  })
}

render () {
  const { addClass } = this.state

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Button</button>
      <div className={!!addClass && 'yourClassName'}>hello</div>
    <>
  )
}
```

And in function like this

```js
function Example() {
  const [addClassValue, addClass] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addClass(!addClassValue)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <div className={addClass ? 'yourClassName'}>hello</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But you do not need classes because React works with components and you can show your modal like

```
function Example() {
  const [addClassValue, addClass] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addClass(!addClassValue)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      // this Component will be only rendered if addClassValue is true
      {addClassValue && <ModalComponent />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Personally I prefer `styles-components` because you can set instant the value and do not need to work with classes etc.